# how to hide tabs in ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i know it's about ng router ,but i'm not familiar with ng,i solved it second router but in third router or deepper it did not work
here is the code:

**html**

```
<ion-tabs class="tabs-icon-top tabs-background-dark tabs-color-light"> 
</ion-tabs>
```

**js**

```
.directive('hideTabs', function($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attributes) {

            scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeEnter', function() {

                scope.$watch(attributes.hideTabs, function(value){
                    $rootScope.hideTabs = 'tabs-item-hide';
                });

            });

            scope.$on('$ionicView.beforeLeave', function() {
                scope.$watch(attributes.hideTabs, function(value){
                    $rootScope.hideTabs = 'tabs-item-hide';
                });
                scope.$watch('$destroy',function(){
                    $rootScope.hideTabs = false;
                })

            });
        }
    };
})
```